# Frequency of data: is quarterly data better than half-year data? Why?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, references, dataset, aggregation

Hi have a dataset which I constructed using quarterly observations (from bank accounts).  I could have also used half-year or yearly data, but I chose quarterly because I thought that higher frequency data could help me obtain more reliable estimates.

The question is, from a theoretical and/or practical perspective, how would you justify the use of higher frequency data?

Any book or paper reference is highly appreciated.

Comment: from a google search of "temporal aggregation" you can find several interesting articles.

Comment: As you can presumably obtain half-year data from quarterly data but not vice versa, the quarterly data contain more information than the half-year data. Whether the extra detail is interesting or effectively noise is a substantive question. What other kind of answer do you seek? Do you want an economics/finance answer, a statistical answer or both?

Comment: Actually I just want a sort of theoretical/statistical answer, not necessarily economical.  One important thing is that I could have obtained half-year data that is not aggregated, in the sense that is not averaged out.  It would be cumulative, but not aggregated.  I just need to make a good argument.  I have the economic intuition clear, but I was wondering whether are there any theoretical/practical reasons why more data is 'better' than less.

Comment: More data per parameter usually means easier estimation. In this context dependence takes much of that away.